# Using local gem with Bundler

Tags: bundler

I created an in-house gem to use with a Rails project that I want to include in my Gemfile.

The gem is hosted in a private repo on Github.com (so `:git` is not an option) so I am assuming the best direction to include the gem is `:path`, e.g.

```
gem 'mygem', :path => '/path/to/gem/dir'
```

I am curious though:

- Where is the ideal place for the gem to be included? (`vendor/` ?)
- If vendor is the best place, then I don't need to add the gem to my project repository (since `vendor/` is ignored by default)
- I am using Capistrano to deploy my project; how should Capistrano be aware of the local gem so that it can deploy it as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the vendor location and have the authentication information for the private gem in the gemfile like this:

gem 'foo', :git => 'https://my_username:my_password@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git'

However, I am guessing that you will be uncomfortable exposing such sensitive information in the gemfile so you can use a git protocol based url in your gem file like this:

git://github.com/username/repo.git

git protocol based urls are read only so your private repo should be intact.

Also, I am sure you can write a capistrano task to deploy a private gem to vendor directory but that might involve putting in your github username/password in the capistrano task. Also, you can prompt for the username/password during deployment as opposed to putting it in the capistrano task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @norman. `gem 'mygem', '~> 0.1.0', :path => 'vendor/git/mygem/'` ended up working after I cloned the gem to the specified path. I was thinking of going down the task route to deploy the gem to `vendor` before the bundle is created for the release but I am hesitant to include my credentials in the repo. (The project is private as well but I am not the only contributor.) My Capistrano script has ssh-agent forwarding enabled so the deploy user should be able to clone the gem without any issues.